# Three.js versus Babylon.js for CAD webapp

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development, drawing, cad

We're developing a CAD webapp. Our webapp will be for drawing buildings and their components (walls, trusses, etc.). Two prominent 3D libraries are Three.js and Babylon.js. What are the pros and cons of each? Which would you recommend for a CAD webapp and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babylon is much more about simulation and 3d rendering so Three.js would seem a better fit.

Three.js is very mature, has been used in other CAD related developments and often used for browser-based diagramming tools. Check out a search of npm to find a number of CAD related modules for three.js.

References for Three.js:

- [OpenJSCAD](http://openjscad.org/) - An open source web-based CAD application
- [Color Tracking CAD Viewer](http://devpost.com/software/cad-viewer)
- [An article on combining 2d from D3.js with 3d from Three.js](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/14/d3js-threejs-and-css-3d-transforms)

References for Babylon.js

- The [only reference I can find](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/17330-how-to-build-a-cad-system/) for using BJS for CAD and it is an unanswered question.

Comment: Thanks for direct and concise answer! Could you provide some citations to substantiate some of the claims like "often used for browser-based diagramming tools" for completeness?

Comment: Hi Scott, sorry - a bit short on time right now but I did some googling to make sure I wasn't making it up before writing the answer. One reference to three.js I can give is to Node-Red which uses three.js to provide a diagrammatic view for flow-based programming. I use that a lot.

Comment: Oops, got my libraries mixed up. Node-Red uses d3.js not three.js but I've added a couple of more relevant references, I'll try to find more if I get time.

Comment: OpenJSCAD is NOT using ThreeJS, it uses lightgl (in V1) and [regl](https://github.com/regl-project/regl) in V2: https://github.com/jscad/OpenJSCAD.org/issues/434